# push view controller by search button

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have `Storyboard` with `UINavigationController` i have created the first screen with searchbar 
i have added second viewcontrol via IB to storyboard

how do i push the second viewcontroller to navigationcontroller ?

i have tried

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    ViewController *screen2 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:screen2 animated:YES];
}
```

i have set `Custom Class` of second view controller to `ViewController2`

but when i run the app and click the search button in keyboard i get the following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ViewController2''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `Xcode` cannot find the `xib` named ViewController2.

You may just call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(@"identifierToViewController")`

But first make sure that your searchViewController is a child of an UINavigationController [image]

Then make sure that the segue has a proper identifier:
[image]

Comment: then i get 
Property 'performSegueWithIdentifier' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: The view controller with the searchbar, did you embed it within a UInavigationController ?

Comment: now i am getting : reason: 'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x16e6de40>) has no segue with identifier 'ViewController2''

Comment: Ok, it's normal, because you didn't set one. Go back to your storyboard and select the arrow between your searchViewcontroller and the one you want to push, and in the column in the right edit the name of the segue's identifier

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your second view controller class name is : `ViewController2`

After that in storyboard give your View Controller's class name and Storyboard Id as @"ViewController2", Please refer screen shot.

[image]

Actually you use wrong method to create instance of UIViewController as it is used when you use xib file.

Change your code like this :

```
    ViewController2 *screen2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:screen2 animated:YES];
```